# Weird Android Kotlin JNI peculiarity can somebody explain

Tags: android, kotlin, java-native-interface

I am using latests, and I am puzzled the below JNI signatures fails propagate param values to my C++ implemenentation. Is this a Kotlin feature?

```
- external fun fff(data:ByteArray,bitmapfile:String)   
- external fun hello(msg:String):String
- external fun addnum2(a:Int, b:Int)
- external fun addnum3(a:Int, b:Int,desc:String)
- external fun addnum4(a:Int, b:Int,desc:String):Int
- external fun addnum5(desc:String,a:Int, b:Int):Int
```

Theh only I found is that, native types `a` and `b` does correctly work and returned the sum. But as soon as I added more params, such as a string, the that's the start of hair pulling below is the error message:

My best guess is that Kotlin is trying to delegate the call, and the object loses scope thus causing the error. Inside C++, it could not read the "hello world" string being passed it is appearing as null. So i tried to return a value such that the caller will block and preserve scope, but still there is no reconciling explanation because the error persist. I step debug in Android studio 3.6.3

Here is log https://gist.github.com/25da55ca5269539e5a884e22d2a3dca5

Here is kotlin:

```
var msg = "hello"   
addnum5(msg,2,4)
```

Here is C++:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_dx_wtf_MainActivity_addnum5(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring desc, 
jint a, jint b) {

    const char *message = env->GetStringUTFChars(desc, 0);
    int sum = 0;
    sum = a + b;
    LOGI("*** ENTRY POINT ***");
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(desc, message);
    return sum;
}
```

The params do not propagate. And the above error `JNI ERROR (app bug): attempt to use stale Local 0x5 (should be 0x1)` I do not understand. I commented out the entire impl body of the C++ and hardcoded `return 69;` and still the error persist = the params do not propagate.

The above error was using an Oppo F9 phone. So I used another Huawei phone, and below is the error:

```
java_vm_ext.cc:570] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x4
```

Comment: Would `fff` happen to be `saveToBitmap`? Please don't needlessly obfuscate your question. Show the native side of the implementation and the call to it, please.

Comment: I don't see what the `addnum` functions have to do with the question, since the stacktrace you've shown us refers to a function with the arguments `byte[], java.lang.String`, which presumably is `fff`.

Comment: I updated with latest log. I attempted several combination of JNI method signatures but I could not make sense of the error. The `desc` that arrives to C++ is null.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger and inspect the various argument values? The only thing I can imagine is that you're somehow looking at the wrong source code.

Comment: This is a fresh mouse-click start-from-scratch Android C++ project and nothing more. The standard `stringFromJNI()` method works. After which, I successively and gradually added methods slowly and so carefully starting from primitive types `int` then adding `String` so carefully in various permutations but..

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please post a complete minimal example with the actual code you're running (and make sure you've rebuilt everything). Your stacktrace suggests to me that you're actually passing the integer 4 where the String should go.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this either., I just tested with a fresh android JNI app as well. Make _sure_ the code you're editing is what is actually running.